# How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, screenshot

I am wondering how my iPhone app can take a screen shot of a specific `UIView` as a `UIImage`.

I tried this code but all I get is a blank image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[myUIView.layer drawInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`myUIView` has dimensions 320x480 an it has some sub-views.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Just check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517922/3908884

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I think you may want `renderInContext`, not `drawInContext`.  drawInContext is more a method you would override...

Note that it may not work in all views, specifically a year or so ago when I tried to use this with the live camera view it did not work.

Comment: Hi Kendall do you have advice for capturing the contents of a UIView not as a still image, but as a video? Thanks for your time! Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956713/simplified-screen-capture-record-video-of-only-what-appears-within-the-layers-o

Answer (score 191):

iOS 7 has a new method that allows you to draw a view hierarchy into the current graphics context. This can be used to get an UIImage very fast.

I implemented a category method on `UIView` to get the view as an `UIImage`:

```
- (UIImage *)pb_takeSnapshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    // old style [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

It is considerably faster then the existing `renderInContext:` method.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1817/_index.html

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT**: An extension that does the same:

```
extension UIView {

    func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        // old style: layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 3**

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
```

Comment: If you have a large UILabel or CAShapeLayer, this does not work, it ends up not drawing anything

Comment: thanks to your swift snippet I solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27764590/1139044.

Comment: it solved my problem. I was using the old version and it was giving me loads of errors! Thanks a million

Comment: I am using the same way to take screen shot of a view. If a view has wkwebview as subview, it's not able to take the screen shot. It shows blank. How to take screen shot properly?

Comment: Calling this during a view controllers transition flashes the end of the transition.

Comment: @Klaas You could use `0` instead of `UIScreen.main.scale`.

Answer (score 64):

You need to capture the **key window** for a screenshot or a UIView. You can do it in **Retina Resolution** using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and set its scale parameter 0.0f. It always captures in native resolution (retina for iPhone 4 and later).

This one does a full screen screenshot (key window)

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code capture a UIView in native resolution

```
CGRect rect = [captureView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This saves the UIImage in jpg format with 95% quality in the app's document folder if you need to do that.

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/capturedImage.jpg"]];    
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 0.95) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: The full screen screenshot sadly doesn't capture the statusbar. Very nice snippet though.

Comment: Is there any way to capture the keyboard?

Comment: @tibidabo
thanks it works. But how can I save more than one image?

Comment: "Great Memory Leak of Chesapeake!" - Hermes Conrad. (Seriously though, manage your CG properly!!)

Answer (score 23):

iOS7 onwards, we have below default methods :

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates
```

Calling above method is faster than trying to render the contents of the current view into a bitmap image yourself.

If you want to apply a graphical effect, such as blur, to a snapshot, use the `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` method instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 18):

There is new API from iOS 10

```
extension UIView {
    func makeScreenshot() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: self.bounds)
        return renderer.image { (context) in
            self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I have created usable extension for UIView to take screenshot in Swift:

```
extension UIView{

var screenshot: UIImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    self.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot
}
}
```

To use it just type:

```
let screenshot = view.screenshot
```

Comment: Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0);` rather than `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);` to use the right scale factor of the device.

Comment: I confirm it works, but using `drawViewHierarchyInRect` instead of `renderInContext ` doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);    
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);  
}
```

This method may put in your Controller class.

Comment: `drawRect` is *not* part of the UIViewController (IIRC). It is part of a UIView. I don't believe it will be called if its in the controller.

Comment: How can i get the saved image path?

Answer (score 7):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension CALayer {
    func makeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        render(in: context)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        return screenshot
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func makeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size)
            return renderer.image { _ in drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
        } else {
            return layer.makeSnapshot()
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let image = view.makeSnapshot()
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to **add the solution code here**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var viewForScreenShot: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var screenShotRenderer: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func makeViewScreenShotButtonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        screenShotRenderer.image = viewForScreenShot.makeSnapshot()
    }
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16C67" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_2214957" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Acg-GO-mMN">
                                <rect key="frame" x="67" y="28" width="240" height="128"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <textField opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4Fr-O3-56t">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="72" y="49" width="96" height="30"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="cLv-es-h7Q"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="96" id="ytF-FH-gdm"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                    </textField>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="0.49277611300000002" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="4Fr-O3-56t" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Acg-GO-mMN" secondAttribute="centerX" id="egj-rT-Gz5"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="4Fr-O3-56t" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Acg-GO-mMN" secondAttribute="centerY" id="ymi-Ll-WIV"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SQq-IE-pvj">
                                <rect key="frame" x="109" y="214" width="157" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="make view screen shot"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="makeViewScreenShotButtonTapped2:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="KSY-ec-uvA"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="CEZ-Ju-Tpq">
                                <rect key="frame" x="67" y="269" width="240" height="128"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="240" id="STo-iJ-rM4"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="tfi-zF-zdn"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.95941069162436543" green="0.95941069162436543" blue="0.95941069162436543" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="SQq-IE-pvj" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="25" id="6x1-iB-gKF"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Acg-GO-mMN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" secondAttribute="leading" id="LUp-Be-FiC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SQq-IE-pvj" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Acg-GO-mMN" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="58" id="Qu0-YT-k9O"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Acg-GO-mMN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Qze-zd-ajY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Acg-GO-mMN" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" secondAttribute="trailing" id="b1d-sp-GHD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="SQq-IE-pvj" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" secondAttribute="centerX" id="qCL-AF-Cro"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Acg-GO-mMN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="u5Y-eh-oSG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="vkx-JQ-pOF"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="screenShotRenderer" destination="CEZ-Ju-Tpq" id="8QB-OE-ib6"/>
                        <outlet property="viewForScreenShot" destination="Acg-GO-mMN" id="jgL-yn-8kk"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="32.799999999999997" y="37.331334332833585"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

### Result

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a comprehensive example. Thank you so much for that!

Comment: this one actually captures everything in the image, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();
```

Apple now allows us to use it in a public application, even though it's a private API

Comment: There are other UIViews on top of myUIView that I don't want to capture.  Otherwise, this would be great.

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not allow:

> `CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();`

Applications should take a screenshot using the `drawRect` method as specified in:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html

Comment: So, What about Matt S's answer?

Answer (score 4):

I created this **extension for save a screen shot** from UIView

```
extension UIView {
func saveImageFromView(path path:String) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

}}
```

**call**:

```
let pathDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first!
let pathImage = "\(pathDocuments)/\(user!.usuarioID.integerValue).jpg"
reportView.saveImageFromView(path: pathImage)
```

If you want to create a png must change:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

by

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Comment: Any ideas why if I screenshot a UITableViewCell I get a blank view, but if I screenshot the tableView I get what I expect?

Comment: I tried with an example (UItableViewController) and It works, maybe put your code here for review

Comment: The trick was that I needed to use a CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -view.frame.origin.y);

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 updated :

```
extension UIView {
   var screenShot: UIImage?  {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: self.bounds)
            return renderer.image { (context) in
                self.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 5);
            if let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
                let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                return screenshot
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet is used to take screenshot :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.muUIView.bounds.size);

[myUIView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**Use  `renderInContext:` method instead of `drawInContext:` method**

`renderInContext:` method renders the receiver and its sublayers into current context. This method
renders directly from the layer tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIImage *)convertViewToImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following UIView category -

```
@implementation UIView (SnapShot)

 - (UIImage *)snapshotImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);        
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];        
    // old style [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];        
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();        
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();        
    return image;
}    
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 // MARK: - Actions
 @objc func imageWasSaved(_ image: UIImage, error: Error?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
     if let error = error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
         return
     }

     print("Image was saved in the photo gallery")
     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"photos-redirect://")!)
 }
   
 func takeScreenshot(of view: UIView) {
     
     let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

     self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, self, #selector(imageWasSaved), nil)
 }
```

Comment: This solution - `drawHierarchy` was proposed several times until now, if older answers. Can you elaborate more on yours, so it can stand up on its own.