# How to render images from UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiimageview

I am looking to load Webview with URL and get content(images) of that.Then scale it to display properly in small size of WebView ot Imageview.

How to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your webView delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

  CGSize thumbsize = CGSizeMake(100,100);

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbsize);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGFloat scalingFactor = thumbsize.width/webView.frame.size.width;
  CGContextScaleCTM(context, scalingFactor,scalingFactor);

  [webView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

  UIImage *thumbImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  //throw it on screen, just for testing
  UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbImage] autorelease];
  [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for giving reply.
In My application WebView continuously getting images from backend server, So it won't got in -WebViewDidFinishLoad method. Like continuously getting images from Webcamera.
Do you have any idea how to do in that case ?

Comment: You might try something with the UIWebView method stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString which I haven't used but presumable would allow you to call some javascript on the web page that checks if an image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you make an UIImage out of a UIView's CALayer. See [How to take an iPhone screenshot of entire view including parts off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328201/how-to-take-an-iphone-screenshot-of-entire-view-including-parts-off-screen) for details.

You can then resize the image:

[The simplest way to resize an UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage/2658960#2658960)