# Take screenshots of a UIView including 3 UITableView(visible+invisible) part

Tags: iphone, uitableview, screenshot

i have a UIView having 3 UITableView and need to take screen shot. But problem is invisible part of the 3 tables . Can anyone help to find a way to take screen shot of the whole view including complete scrolled contents of the tables.

Comment: Do you want to take a screenshot from your computer, or have the image rendered in the app itself?

Comment: You can use this [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328201/how-to-take-an-iphone-screenshot-of-entire-view-including-parts-off-screen/8033794#8033794) to get full view of tableview.

Answer (score 1):

This helps get the contents of a layer (ie. and thus a UIView)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableView.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[tableView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: hi thanks very much for your answer and time.

I actually need to take screen shot of all the tables with their visible and invisible parts including other parts of the self.view.

I have tried your code with self.table2 in place of tableView
Result : Shows only table2 visible part.
 
Tried with self.view also.
Result : Shows the view with table1.table2,table3 having their visible parts only. But not showing the invisible parts of those 3 tables.
thanks  again and appreciate your effort.

Comment: The cells off screen are technically draw on the view (for good reasons). So you'd have to create a loop to take the image and then scroll the tableview down. Then you'd probably need to patch the images.