# iOS7's drawViewHierarchyInRect doesn't work?

Tags: ipad, graphics, ios7

From what I've read, iOS7's new [drawViewHierarchyInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) is supposed to be faster than CALayer's [renderInContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext:). And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964153/ios-whats-the-fastest-most-performant-way-to-make-a-screenshot-programaticall) and [this](http://blog.xamarin.com/snapshotting-views-in-ios-7/), it should be a simple matter of calling:

```
[myView drawViewHierarchyInRect:myView.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

instead of

```
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

However, when I try this, I just get blank images. Full code that does the capture, where "self" is a subclass of UIView,

```
        // YES = opaque. Ignores alpha channel, so less memory is used.
        // This method for some reasons renders the
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, self.window.screen.scale);    // Still slow.

    if ( [AIMAppDelegate isOniOS7OrNewer] )
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES]; // Doesn't work!
    else
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     // Works!

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    contentImageView.image = image; // this is empty if done using iOS7's way
```

and contentImageView is a UIImageView that is added as a subView to self during initialization.

Additionally, the drawing that I want captured in the image is contained in other sub-views that are also added to self as a sub-view during initialization (including contentImageView).

Any ideas why this is failing when using drawViewHierarchyInRect?

*** Update ***

I get an image if I draw a specific sub-view, such as:

```
[contentImageView drawViewHierarchyInRect:contentImageView.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

or

```
[self.curvesView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.curvesView.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

however I need all the visible sub-views combined into one image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with `self.bounds` rather than `self.frame`—it’s possible you’re getting an image of your view rendered outside the boundaries of the image context you’ve created.

Comment: Haha, through experimentation I just found the same result. That was the issue! Thanks.

Comment: Only other weird thing is that drawViewHierarchyInRect is actually a good bit SLOWER than renderInContext. I thought it should be faster? Any idea why it's not?

Comment: Might be the `afterScreenUpdates:YES`—I believe that forces it to wait for the next time the layer tree gets presented. Does the speed change if you turn that off?

Comment: In my case, some times `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` returns NO. I get the same result by using both self.frame and self.bounds. However, my issue is solved by using `renderInContext` as told by @VernJensen above. Thanks.