# How do I save the contents of a UIWebView as an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to save the content of `UIWebView` as an image. The code I have only saves the content of the webpage that is visible on the screen.

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webCanvas.frame.size);
    [self.webCanvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil,nil,nil);
}
```

I want it so it will save the whole webpage in the `UIWebView` including the part of the website that is not visible on screen. Is this possible?

Comment: the strategy should be something like... make a UIWebView that is big enough to render everything... render that to an offscreen context, save that as an image... if some part of that doesn't work your job gets harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check these:- 
[Convert UIWebview contents to a UIImage when the webview is larger than the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475397/convert-uiwebview-contents-to-a-uiimage-when-the-webview-is-larger-than-the-scre?rq=1) 
 [How to take an iPhone screenshot of entire view including parts off screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328201/how-to-take-an-iphone-screenshot-of-entire-view-including-parts-off-screen)
 Hope this will help you.