# Emailing a Screenshot? (ObjC)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email, screenshot

How do you save a screenshot you take from your code, and put it into an email within your app?

Comment: Also, this probably assumes Cocoa and should be tagged as such.

Comment: iOS, for iPhone. I'm developing with cocos2d.

Comment: Retagged: Added iphone and cocoa-touch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a bit of research of other articles on Stack Overflow.

This shows how to take a screenshot: [how to take a screenshot of the iPhone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically)

You may also want to take a look at this, its a quick and easy method provided by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1703.html

This article shows how to send an email: [How can I send mail from an iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310946/how-can-i-send-mail-from-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was wondering how I can attach the screenshot into an email.

Comment: Check this out, it shows you how to add an attachment using the methods shown in the second link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the help and second reply! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code of how you got this to work. I'm looking for the code once I have the image and want to send it. Thanks