# Determining if Airplane Mode is enabled on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

UPDATE: As of some version of iOS 8 (8.3, maybe), GPS hardware can be turned on even in airplane mode (i.e., you can get GPS location even in airplane mode). This renders this question moot.

--

Is it possible to programatically determine if an iPhone is in Airplane Mode? I specifically want to know if it's in AirPlane Mode, as opposed to having (or not having) a network connection. This question has been asked a lot, but every answer I've seen has referred to Apple's Reachability code to determine if a network connection is available.

I'm writing an app that uses the iPhone's GPS. At the moment, if Airplane Mode is on and my app is launched, my location manager object still appears to exist and still appears to be giving me a (cached?) location. The little GPS icon appears in the status bar to let me know that my app is determining a location.

[image: Airplane Mode and GPS arrow indicator]

I want to know if the phone's in Airplane Mode so that I can not initialise the location manager object and I can change my UI to indicate to the user that GPS functionality is not available.

The GPS functionality can obviously be used regardless of network connectivity, so a lack of network connectivity strikes me as being a poor proxy for Airplane Mode. I don't appear to get any specific errors (through locationManager: didFailWithError) when in Airplane Mode, just a generic error that I'm assuming could come from a number of sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar requirements for my app, except I knew in advance that it would most likely be used in a "no cell signal" environment (camping in a remote area) and that the user might put the device in airplane mode to conserve batteries, without realizing it shuts down GPS.

Since airplane mode does not result in an didFailWithError, and locationServicesEnabled returns yes, I set a timer for 60 seconds, and if no GPS reading is returned before the timer expires, I display a message to the user telling them that GPS data can't be read, and suggest they check that airplane mode is not enabled, and that they ensure they have a clear view of the sky.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing.

Comment: The other case that should be mentioned to the user in the error message, is that they should verify the app has been granted access to GPS data.  I had a user insist the app was broken, only to find out he had hit "Don't Allow" on the permission pop-up.

Comment: You should get a `kCLErrorDenied` error result in the `locationManager:didFailWithError:` method if the user has not enabled location services for your app. I've got a specific error dialog to deal that with case. If the device in in flight mode, you get the generic `kCLErrorLocationUnknown` error.

Comment: I've been testing the extensively under iOS7 and iOS8; In Airplane mode, LocationServices will call the locationManager:didFailWithError: delegate with an error of kCLErrorDomain 0. If your app is authorized to use location service, authorizationStatus will be kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized as you are authorized ... the hardware is simply missing the power to fulfill the request. (I conjecture that a bad GPS chip would return similar results.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible to get this information, at least using public classes, but if what you need is to alert the user that he's in Airplane Mode, so with limited app functionality, you may set in your Info.plist file the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` property to "true". Then when Airplane mode is set you will get this message.
By the way note that this approach is better than just checking the Airplane Mode status, other than because it is system supported, as if the user enables Airplane mode and then re-enables Wi-Fi (still staying in Airplane Mode) then the system alert will not be displayed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already doing this, but it seems to me to be a bit of a fudge (as my app doesn't need any network connectivity, let alone WiFi connectivity). I also think it has negative ramifications for battery life, as my understanding is that it keeps the WiFi connection active. Maybe you're right - maybe there's no way to get this information.

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to [take a screenshot of the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically) and look at the colors present in that region. If they're orange, you're in airplane mode.

Comment: I like your lateral thinking, but I imagine this solution would be prone to breaking under different versions of iOS and maybe on different hardware. If I can't get anything else to work, I might give this a go.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a hacky solution. A built-in API would be far preferable.

Comment: When you take a screenshot on the device the status bar is not included.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Mine didn't, when taken on the phone, using the "approved" API.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be trying to check if Airplane Mode is enabled or not.  What if Apple makes a change to how Airplane Mode works, where it will leave the GPS equipment enabled even when turned on?  The best way to reliably detect whether GPS services are enabled is to implement the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) and let the APIs **tell** you whether GPS is available or not

Examining the `NSError` it may pass to you will let you know if there are problems to

Comment: Yes, but this won't tell me that GPS is unavailable due to the device being in flight mode.

Comment: The airplane mode setting does not alter the results of [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] OR of [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus].