# Airplane mode on iPod Touch -- revisited

Tags: wifi, ipod-touch, noise, airplane-mode

The situation is this:  We have an app that records sound.  If the app is running on a second generation iPod Touch and airplane mode is OFF then there are periodic noises that end up in the recording due to the WIFI activity of the iPod.

So I want to detect that we're running on a second generation iPod Touch (which I know how to do), and, if so, tell the user to turn on airplane mode, if it's not already on.  Note that **it's NOT SUFFICIENT to simply know that WIFI is unreachable** as the iPod will continue to try to "talk" to WIFI every 12 seconds, even if there is no WIFI connection available.

So, does anyone know of a way to determine if airplane mode is on or off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a (legal) way to capture the ENTIRE screen under iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997556/is-there-a-legal-way-to-capture-the-entire-screen-under-ios)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- You're being pretty nit picky.  This question was posted yesterday and got only a few views.  So I attacked the problem from a different angle.  The other question drew a lot of interest (presumably because everyone thinks they're an expert on screen shots).  The two questions are only related in that they both have the same final goal -- they ask two entirely different things.

Comment: It is not appropriate to ask the same question repeatedly. Please see the Stack Overflow FAQ for information on duplicate questions and on getting good answers to your questions.

Comment: They are **TWO DISTINCT QUESTIONS** that only happen to be related due to a common goal.

Comment: Then the other question is a duplicate and should be closed. I'll mark it as such. :)

Comment: @HotLicks, you're right, they are two different questions, but given that 100% of the comments and answers on the other question are about networking (and not screenshots), I think it would make the most sense for you to delete this one and change the title of the other one. Not your fault, just how it played out. (You can ask a new question about status bar image capture if you like, but I don't think it's a good way to fix your particular problem.)

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate question. The whole point of SO is to record this sort of information for people looking at it in Google. Like he said, they have a common goal, but the answers would be very distinct.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696062/determining-if-airplane-mode-is-enabled-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no way to do this.