# Can't get the screenshot of fullscreen in ios

Tags: ios

This is my code..

```
extern CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548);
CGImageRef cgoriginal = UIGetScreenImage();
CGImageRef cgimg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgoriginal, frame);            
UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];    
CGImageRelease(cgoriginal);                
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

It takes screen shot but not full screen. I know this problem in CGRect frame. But I don't know, how to fix that..

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to get the full screen, including the top status bar.

Comment: @HotLicks:There is no possible to get full screenshot of view huh?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997556/is-there-a-legal-way-to-capture-the-entire-screen-under-ios

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that UIGetScreenImage is a private API, so it will be rejected. If you want to do something similar you can try to use -renderInContext on the window layer or -drawViewHierchyInRect(only ios7).
This method should be used as a category on UIView:

```
- (UIImage *) imageByRenderingViewOpaque:(BOOL) yesOrNO {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, yesOrNO, 0);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

You have also this method that you can call on UIScree instance `- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates`, but that will return only a view not an image.