# Detect if Airplane mode is ON or OFF in iOS

Tags: ios, airplane-mode

I am trying to detect the airplane mode using private framework - "AppSupport framework". I have changed the content of RadiosPreferences.h file in it. New content is

```
@protocol RadiosPreferencesDelegate
-(void)airplaneModeChanged;
@end

@interface RadiosPreferences : NSObject
{
    struct __SCPreferences *_prefs;
    int _applySkipCount;
    id <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> _delegate;
    BOOL _isCachedAirplaneModeValid;
    BOOL _cachedAirplaneMode;
    BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)dealloc;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL airplaneMode;
- (void)refresh;
- (void)initializeSCPrefs:(id)arg1;
- (void)notifyTarget:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)synchronize;
- (void *)getValueForKey:(id)arg1;
- (void)setValue:(void *)arg1 forKey:(id)arg2;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly; // @synthesize notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
@property(nonatomic) id <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> delegate; // @synthesize delegate=_delegate;

@end
```

I followed below link for this.

[Detect if iPhone is in Airplane mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264053/detect-if-iphone-is-in-airplane-mode)

Once done, it gives me this error

```
ld: framework not found AppSupport
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried all the solutions. But nothing works for me. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When [I tried a couple of years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997556/is-there-a-legal-way-to-capture-the-entire-screen-under-ios) there was no way to do this "legally".

Comment: @HotLicks I don't have to upload this app on appstore. So I don't bother about it. I just want to know the way no matter using private frameworks.

Comment: I believe there was a suggestion or two in my link.

Comment: @HotLicks I see no way to get this airplane mode detection in your link. I think to detect airplane mode using Reachability is not the correct way.

Comment: Hi Funny, did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same in my app (also not for the store) and would be grateful for any pointers.