# How can I tell if WiFi is on and not connected?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

Is it possible for my app to tell if the user has turned on WiFi but is NOT connected to a WiFi network?  I can not find any way to determine the power on or off status of the WiFi.

(Note that this question is not "how do I tell if I have a WiFi connection".  That is easily handled by the sample reachablilty code).

Comment: No, not that I can tell.  I tried to find out if the phone is in [airplane mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981427/airplane-mode-on-ipod-touch-revisited) but could not.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: try using reachebility class provide by apple you can ditect your wifi on or off...