# How can I know if airplane mode is on?

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager, airplane-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining if Airplane Mode is enabled on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696062/determining-if-airplane-mode-is-enabled-on-an-iphone)

My application is using the GPS, and I check its availability with :

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

My problem is that if the user turns on airplane mode, these methods don't detect that the GPS is unavailable, and it ends with errors.

I try to add SBUsesNetwork in my plist file, but without success.

I found some threads talking about Reachability (that I use to check the internet connection), but it is not an option since the user can disable his connection to internet (a tourist, e.g) but still want GPS location ?

How can I know if the airplane mode is activated ?

Comment: "it ends with errors" - whenever asking a question on Stack Overflow, if you are trying to resolve errors, post the errors you are getting.

Comment: Well, what I mean is that it calls `connection:finishedWithError:`, which is logic as the phone is on airplane mode. But the error is : `Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn't be completed (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"`

Comment: Then where is the problem?  It's correctly reporting that it cannot provide updates.  How you handle that condition is up to you.

Comment: I'd like to avoid allocating a locationManager not to use it, but I think I'll do that anyway, if I can't find a better way to do it.

Comment: @Jim Also, I'm already checking the internet connection, and I wanted to display only one alert saying that the internet connection and/or the GPS is disable.

Comment: this is very close to your: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/detect-airplane-mode-on-ios/