# Distinguish AirPlane mode and no internet connection

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, reachability, airplane-mode

I have read discussion over here:
[Determining if Airplane Mode is enabled on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696062/determining-if-airplane-mode-is-enabled-on-an-iphone)

I conclude that I cannot determine whether AirPlane mode is ON or OFF if i got Cellular Data OFF and WiFi OFF. BUT recently i have checked how Facebook solve this problem. I see when I lunch application with AirPlane mode and disabled Wi-Fi I receive:
[image: message 'Turn Off Airplane Mode or User Wi-Fi to Access Data']

And when i disable AirPlane and disable Cellular and Wi-Fi:
[image: message 'No internet connection']

How should I distinguish these two situations?

Thread related to this question:
[How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)