# Saving screenshots in my app in Xcode

Tags: xcode, screenshot

How can I make abutton that take a screenshot then save it in my app in gallery (another view )

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to take a screenshot of the iPhone programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: [how to take a screenshot of the iPhone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically)

It explains how to do exactly what you want.

To make an image gallery i advise to use [Fgallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone).

Comment: Ok ihave image of the screen but how can I make a gallery or table to view all the screenshots I take

Comment: i added a link to the github of Fgallery, really nice gallery lib for iOS ^_^

Comment: If you can answer a question by pointing to another stack overflow question, then you should just mark this as a duplicate rather than linking back to the other question.