# iPhone snapshot including keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, snapshot, uiwindow

I'm looking for the proper way to snapshot the entire iPhone screen including the keyboard.

i found some code to snapshot the screen:

```
CGRect screenCaptureRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
UIView *viewWhereYouWantToScreenCapture = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
//screen capture code
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenCaptureRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[viewWhereYouWantToScreenCapture drawViewHierarchyInRect:screenCaptureRect afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but it doesn't capture the keyboard as well. it looks like the keyWindow doesn't include the keyboard view.

btw I need `UIImage` as final result, not `UIView`, so I can't use other snapshot API's.

Any ideas of to do that and with best performance?

Comment: kindly check this post <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically</a>

Answer (score 9):

Keyboard is placed in other window. And in iOS9 keyboard accessory placed in different one. So the best solution is to render all windows.

Here is working code:

```
- (UIImage*)fullScreenShot {
    CGSize imgSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO, 0);
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        if (![window respondsToSelector:@selector(screen)] || window.screen == [UIScreen mainScreen]) {
            [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        }
    }
    UIImage* img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the keyboard is displayed in another window. So instead of getting only one window using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`, you should get all windows using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` and for each of them call `[viewWhereYouWantToScreenCapture drawViewHierarchyInRect:screenCaptureRect afterScreenUpdates:NO]` so that all of them are drawn inside one image context.

Answer (score 1):

iOS renders keyboard under a window with the description `UITextEffectsWindow`.

You can iterate all windows using and find the right one using:

`for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) { 
      if ([window.class.description isEqualToString:@"UITextEffectsWindow"]) {
          return window;
      }
}`

When you're done, you can render it into your context using `renderInContext` or `drawViewHierarchyInRect`. `renderInContext` might be slower but safer (because it's done on the main thread,) and `drawViewHierarchyInRect` is faster (doesn't affect the main thread,) but might crash due to a bug in iOS code.

Comment: is this using a private api?

Comment: Taking a screenshot of the keyboard is not using private api. However, you won't be seeing custom keyboard (such as Swiftkey) in your screenshot. The window is not from your process.