# Creating image of another view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing Swift and iOS and I have a question.

Lets say I am in `ViewController1` and I want an image of `TableViewController1` after that class calls `viewDidLoad()`, is this possible?

I know its possible to convert the *current* view into a UIImage etc, but is it possible to do it of another view?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is the plan. I call `func x()` in `ViewController1` . What this method should essentially do is return a `UIImage` of `TableViewController1` instance after `viewDidLoad()` was called in `TableViewController1`. Is this clear?

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: @Buntylm, how is the eedit?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to UIView which you can use in viewDidAppear() for example to make screenshot of screen

```
extension UIView{

 var screenshot: UIImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    self.layer.render(in: context!)
    let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenShot!
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a "screenshot" so to speak of whatever is drawn on the screen.
So, if your view controller is currently on the screen, you can capture it from any event/handler.

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to define the area. Look in the documentation for further steps.

Or

[See this answer for an actual method that can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610604/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-the-iphone-programmatically#3635080)