# how to take screen shot and that screen shot save in album

Tags: objective-c

I am working on application of greeting cards in I have taken screen shot and save in gallery so give any suggestion and source code which apply in my code

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
- (UIImage *) captureScreen {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Then save the image to camera roll using the following tutorial
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/camera/save-an-image-to-camera-roll.html