# How to capture a designated regional screenshot on screen in Xcode

Tags: ios, screenshot

How to capture a designated regional screenshot on screen in Xcode?

For example, I hope to capture a region of (0,100,320,200) on screen and save to UIImage object?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Below code for full screen screenshot (key window)

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Try This code capture a UIView in native resolution

```
CGRect rect = [captureView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This saves the UIImage in jpg format with 95% quality in the app's document folder if you need to do that.

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/capturedImage.jpg"]];    
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 0.95) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Source : [How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)