# How to implement range slider in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicontrol

I'm trying to implement Range Slider and I used custom control called [NMRangeSlider](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nmrangeslider).

But when I use it, the slider doesn't appear at all. Could it be also because it's all written in Objective-C?

This is how I've currently implemented it:

```
var rangeSlider = NMRangeSlider(frame: CGRectMake(16, 6, 275, 34))
rangeSlider.lowerValue = 0.54
rangeSlider.upperValue = 0.94
self.view.addSubview(rangeSlider)
```

Comment: Could you show some code how you're using it? I've used this before with no problems.

Comment: yes for sure. I'm trying to add it programmatically like this: 
var rangeSlider = NMRangeSlider(frame: CGRectMake(16, 6, 275, 34))
        rangeSlider.lowerValue = 0.54
        rangeSlider.upperValue = 0.94
        self.view.addSubview(rangeSlider)

Comment: @Michal excuse me, when i saw the demo, i noticed : to implement the range slider what we do is just to make the view class is NMRangeSlider.
Right ?
and did you use this framework with swift ? or Obj-C

Comment: See my answer now - you need to set all the views for the components of the slider. Then it will work. (tested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE:

It did not show to me, because it was all white. So the solution, without using any other framework and sticking with this one - you need to set all the views for all the components and then it will display well:

[image]

---

I have tried to import it in Swift as I used it before in Objective-C code, but without any luck. If I set everything properly and add it either in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`, nothing gets displayed. One thing is worth mentioning, though - when I enter **View Debug Hierarchy**, the slider actually *is* there on the canvas:

[image]

But it's simply not rendered with all the colors that I did set before adding in it to the view. For the record - this is the code I used:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var rangeSlider = NMRangeSlider(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 275, 34))
    rangeSlider.lowerValue = 0.54
    rangeSlider.upperValue = 0.94
    
    let range = 10.0
    let oneStep = 1.0 / range
    let minRange: Float = 0.05
    rangeSlider.minimumRange = minRange
    
    let bgImage = UIView(frame: rangeSlider.frame)
    bgImage.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    rangeSlider.trackImage = bgImage.pb_takeSnapshot()
    
    let trackView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, rangeSlider.frame.size.width, 29))
    trackView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    trackView.opaque = false
    trackView.alpha = 0.3
    rangeSlider.trackImage = UIImage(named: "")
    
    let lowerThumb = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 29))
    lowerThumb.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    let lowerThumbHigh = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 29))
    lowerThumbHigh.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    
    rangeSlider.lowerHandleImageNormal = lowerThumb.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.lowerHandleImageHighlighted = lowerThumbHigh.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.upperHandleImageNormal = lowerThumb.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.upperHandleImageHighlighted = lowerThumbHigh.pb_takeSnapshot()
    
    self.view.addSubview(rangeSlider)

    self.view.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
}
```

Using the method for capturing the UIView as UIImage mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview):

```
extension UIView {
    func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

---

#### Other solution:

You can also try [sgwilly/RangeSlider](https://github.com/sgwilly/RangeSlider) instead, it's written in Swift and therefore you won't even need a Bridging Header.

Comment: Try entering the `Debug View Hierarchy` and see if it's on canvas.

Comment: And is it all see through (invisible) or white or what does it look like?

Comment: all the components of the slider are white !!
it seems that it didn't take the default values that the slider provide it!!!

Comment: i wander why that happen !!
in the demo of NMRangSlider, the just change the class of the view to NMRangeSlide, then alll it works !!
i feel so bad really :|

Comment: They shouldn't be white if you copy and paste my code I put in my answer.

Comment: Also try changing the color of your views background (`self.view.backgroundColor = .grayColor()` for example) and maybe you'll see it where it is.

Comment: this is a snapshot for it :
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12219139/8475614/1faadb7c-20c2-11e5-8217-1671ff5416cc.png

Comment: My code does not create that - try the code that is in my answer (it changed)

Comment: yeah i tried the new code,
the slider appear with two white thumb, but the trakImage doesn't appear even if i assign an image to it.
but can you tell me why if i hint this code:
rangeSlider.lowerHandleImageNormal = lowerThumb.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.lowerHandleImageHighlighted = lowerThumbHigh.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.upperHandleImageNormal = lowerThumb.pb_takeSnapshot()
    rangeSlider.upperHandleImageHighlighted = lowerThumbHigh.pb_takeSnapshot()
the slider will disappear again ?!

Comment: My bad, the CGContext doesn't like the blackColor, try changing this line `bgImage.backgroundColor = .blackColor()` to `.greenColor()` to see if it works.

Comment: It disappears because it does not know what to display, since you're not assigning it. There are *no default values* - you have to set everything yourself. If nothing happened, then you're doing something different. I'm building the code **AS-IS** in Xcode 6.4, iPhone 6 Simulator against SDK 8.4 and I'm getting the slider with green background.

Answer (score 6):

To create a custom Range Slider I found a good solution here: [range finder tutorial iOS 8](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift) but I needed this in swift 3 for my project. I updated this for Swift 3 iOS 10 here:

1. in your main view controller add this to viewDidLayOut to show a range slider.

   ```
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
      let margin: CGFloat = 20.0
      let width = view.bounds.width - 2.0 * margin
      rangeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin + topLayoutGuide.length + 170, width: width, height: 31.0)
   }
   ```
2. create the helper function to print slider output below viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   ```
   func rangeSliderValueChanged() { //rangeSlider: RangeSlider
       print("Range slider value changed: \(rangeSlider.lowerValue) \(rangeSlider.upperValue) ")//(\(rangeSlider.lowerValue) \(rangeSlider.upperValue))
   }
   ```
3. Create the file **RangeSlider.swift** and add this to it:

   ```
   import UIKit

   import QuartzCore

   class RangeSlider: UIControl {

    var minimumValue = 0.0
    var maximumValue = 1.0
    var lowerValue = 0.2
    var upperValue = 0.8

    let trackLayer = RangeSliderTrackLayer()//= CALayer() defined in RangeSliderTrackLayer.swift
    let lowerThumbLayer = RangeSliderThumbLayer()//CALayer()
    let upperThumbLayer = RangeSliderThumbLayer()//CALayer()
    var previousLocation = CGPoint()

    var trackTintColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    var trackHighlightTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.45, blue: 0.94, alpha: 1.0)
    var thumbTintColor = UIColor.white

    var curvaceousness : CGFloat = 1.0

    var thumbWidth: CGFloat {
      return CGFloat(bounds.height)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)

      trackLayer.rangeSlider = self
      trackLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
      layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

      lowerThumbLayer.rangeSlider = self
      lowerThumbLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
      layer.addSublayer(lowerThumbLayer)

      upperThumbLayer.rangeSlider = self
      upperThumbLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
      layer.addSublayer(upperThumbLayer)

     }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    func updateLayerFrames() {
      trackLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: bounds.height / 3)
      trackLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

      let lowerThumbCenter = CGFloat(positionForValue(value: lowerValue))

      lowerThumbLayer.frame = CGRect(x: lowerThumbCenter - thumbWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0,
                                  width: thumbWidth, height: thumbWidth)
      lowerThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()

      let upperThumbCenter = CGFloat(positionForValue(value: upperValue))
      upperThumbLayer.frame = CGRect(x: upperThumbCenter - thumbWidth / 2.0, y: 0.0,
                                  width: thumbWidth, height: thumbWidth)
      upperThumbLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func positionForValue(value: Double) -> Double {
     return Double(bounds.width - thumbWidth) * (value - minimumValue) /
       (maximumValue - minimumValue) + Double(thumbWidth / 2.0)
    }

     override var frame: CGRect {
      didSet {
         updateLayerFrames()
       }
     }

      override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
         previousLocation = touch.location(in: self)

         // Hit test the thumb layers
         if lowerThumbLayer.frame.contains(previousLocation) {
           lowerThumbLayer.highlighted = true
         } else if upperThumbLayer.frame.contains(previousLocation) {
           upperThumbLayer.highlighted = true
         }

          return lowerThumbLayer.highlighted || upperThumbLayer.highlighted
      }

      func boundValue(value: Double, toLowerValue lowerValue: Double, upperValue: Double) -> Double {
        return min(max(value, lowerValue), upperValue)
      }

      override func continueTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        // 1. Determine by how much the user has dragged
        let deltaLocation = Double(location.x - previousLocation.x)
        let deltaValue = (maximumValue - minimumValue) * deltaLocation / Double(bounds.width - thumbWidth)

         previousLocation = location

         // 2. Update the values
        if lowerThumbLayer.highlighted {
           lowerValue += deltaValue
           lowerValue = boundValue(value: lowerValue, toLowerValue: minimumValue, upperValue: upperValue)
       } else if upperThumbLayer.highlighted {
         upperValue += deltaValue
         upperValue = boundValue(value: upperValue, toLowerValue: lowerValue, upperValue: maximumValue)
       }

       // 3. Update the UI
       CATransaction.begin()
       CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

       updateLayerFrames()

       CATransaction.commit()

        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)

         return true
    }

     override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {
       lowerThumbLayer.highlighted = false
       upperThumbLayer.highlighted = false
     }
   }
   ```
4. Next add the thumb layer subclass file **RangeSliderThumbLayer.swift** and add this to it:

   ```
     import UIKit

     class RangeSliderThumbLayer: CALayer {
        var highlighted = false
        weak var rangeSlider: RangeSlider?

     override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
       if let slider = rangeSlider {
         let thumbFrame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 2.0, dy: 2.0)
         let cornerRadius = thumbFrame.height * slider.curvaceousness / 2.0
         let thumbPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: thumbFrame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

         // Fill - with a subtle shadow
         let shadowColor = UIColor.gray
         ctx.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0), blur: 1.0, color: shadowColor.cgColor)
         ctx.setFillColor(slider.thumbTintColor.cgColor)
         ctx.addPath(thumbPath.cgPath)
         ctx.fillPath()

       // Outline
       ctx.setStrokeColor(shadowColor.cgColor)
       ctx.setLineWidth(0.5)
       ctx.addPath(thumbPath.cgPath)
       ctx.strokePath()

       if highlighted {
           ctx.setFillColor(UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.1).cgColor)
           ctx.addPath(thumbPath.cgPath)
           ctx.fillPath()
       }
     }
    }
   }
   ```
5. Finally add the track layer subclass file **RangeSliderTrackLayer.swift** and add the following to it:

   ```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import QuartzCore

    class RangeSliderTrackLayer: CALayer {
     weak var rangeSlider: RangeSlider?

     override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
       if let slider = rangeSlider {
         // Clip
         let cornerRadius = bounds.height * slider.curvaceousness / 2.0
         let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
         ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)

         // Fill the track
         ctx.setFillColor(slider.trackTintColor.cgColor)
         ctx.addPath(path.cgPath)
         ctx.fillPath()

         // Fill the highlighted range
         ctx.setFillColor(slider.trackHighlightTintColor.cgColor)
         let lowerValuePosition =  CGFloat(slider.positionForValue(value: slider.lowerValue))
         let upperValuePosition = CGFloat(slider.positionForValue(value: slider.upperValue))
         let rect = CGRect(x: lowerValuePosition, y: 0.0, width: upperValuePosition - lowerValuePosition, height: bounds.height)
       ctx.fill(rect)
      }
     }
    }
   ```

Build Run and Get:
[image]

Comment: in the `viewDidLoad` you should insert `rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rangeSliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)`so that moves of the cursors are detected

Comment: Nice solution. When used in a modalView, however, I had cross-talks between the rangeSlider and the gestureRecognizer managing the dismissal of the modalView, so that I had to temporarily inhibit the latter, following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59462475/17265403 and my comment to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let margin: CGFloat = 20.0
    let width = view.bounds.width - 2.0 * margin
    rangeSlider.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin + topLayoutGuide.length,
        width: width, height: 31.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the range slider using :
https://github.com/Zengzhihui/RangeSlider

In the GZRangeSlider class, there is a method called :
private func setLabelText()

In that method, just put :

```swift
leftTextLayer.frame = CGRectMake(leftHandleLayer.frame.minX - 0.5 * (kTextWidth - leftHandleLayer.frame.width), leftHandleLayer.frame.minY - kTextHeight, kTextWidth, kTextHeight)

rightTextLayer.frame = CGRectMake(rightHandleLayer.frame.minX - 0.5 * (kTextWidth - leftHandleLayer.frame.width), leftTextLayer.frame.minY, kTextWidth, kTextHeight)
```

to animate the lower and upper labels..

This one is working well for me and its in swift.. just try it..