# UIPickerView PanGesture is coinciding with Modally presented VC dismiss gesture

Tags: swift, uipickerview, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have added simple UIPickerView in PresentedViewController as shown below, but problem is when I am swapping down at red point, Instead of reaction from UIPickerView whole ViewController in coming down.

[image]

I went through solutions provided here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57635168/4614493
But problem is UIPickerView does not provide any function for existing gestures as per my knowledge to avoid other panGestures because of which whole ViewController is coming down.

How may I avoid same, Let me know if something is not clear enough.

I don't think it's required but you may find relevant code in TaskViewController here in my project https://github.com/kautsiitd/Calendar.git

Comment: How did you add the Done button? e.g. UIBarButton, etc.

Comment: @DevKyle It's Simple toolBar with FlexibleSpace and Done Button with some Constraints added in xib of TaskViewController.. You may find same in PickerView in xib.. and taking outlets on tapping actions..