# Is there a way to disable the reachability swipe down gesture from an ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this feature whilst using your ionic app

[image]

My Issue is, I'm using the `ion-datepicker` and I've noticed that if a user swipes down fast enough it will trigger this "reachability" mode, I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this?

I understand its an accessibility feature, but Im hoping there's a way you can easily toggl this on and off when certain features are used.

From this question [Disable iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture in iOS game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694506/disable-ios-reachability-swipe-gesture-in-ios-game) it appears as if it possible using swift

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about this, but maybe try to turn swipeGesture for ion-content to false when u are on a specific page or from app module turn swipe gesture off for all the application in case u have much swipe downs in or the application... what I know about swipeGesture for ios that if u swipe the page from left to right then it go back to the previous page and if we set swipe gesture to false then this act stops ios default back behavior so perhaps give it a try and see if ut also fix ur problem

Comment: @MostafaHarb thanks will give this a try

Comment: well i think you can target this with @nativescript/capacitor and just execute that line no?