# Is it possible to move the popup location of the default DatePicker on iOS in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, datepicker

The Xamarin.Forms [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datepicker?view=xamarin-forms) on iOS brings up a popup picker at the bottom of the screen when tapped, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Unfortunately when the user swipes down to change the date quickly, this can trigger the [Reachability](https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-use-reachability-on-ios-15/) feature where the app slides down so the top half of the screen is easier to reach. I understand that this is an operating system-level feature and that iOS users may be familiar with it, but I would like to modify my app to make it a little more user friendly.

One solution might be to move the popup higher so there's less of a chance of swiping off the bottom of the screen, as shown in the following mock screenshot:

[image]

Is this possible using Xamarin.Forms or with some type of DatePicker renderer? I know I can modify the DatePicker itself with a renderer, but I'm not sure if I can modify the popup window.

### Update 1

This post also discusses a similar topic - how to disable the Reachability feature for an app:

[Disable iOS Reachability Swipe Gesture in iOS game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694506/disable-ios-reachability-swipe-gesture-in-ios-game)

Unfortunately the current (as of January 17, 2022) conclusion is that there is a bug which makes this particular call broken, so attempting to solve the problem by disabling Reachability in code is currently not possible using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following code .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace MyForms.iOS
{
    internal class MyPickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);


            var frame1 = Control.InputAccessoryView.Frame;
            frame1.Y = -100;
            Control.InputAccessoryView.Frame = frame1;

            var frame2 = Control.InputView.Frame;
            frame2.Y = -100;
            Control.InputView.Frame = frame2;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a small problem , the popup picker will reset the location(bottom) if it loses focus .

[image]