# How to Disable iOS Swipe Down Reachability Programitctly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build a game app with Swift that should disable swipe down ios reachability in a specific view controller how can I do that?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq8nB.png)

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694506/disable-ios-reachability-swipe-gesture-in-ios-game although it doesn't necessarily look like there's a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this, you may need to override `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` to tell it the edge of the screen you want to prevent accepting gestures

so you can try:

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return [.bottom]
}
```