# How to take screenshot of a UIView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, screenshot

I have a UIView named overView:

```
overView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/25, self.view.frame.height/25, self.view.frame.width/1.3, self.view.frame.height/1.2)
```

I want to take a screenshot of this view only and not my entire screen. And make the screenshot of size:

```
 (CGSizeMake(2480,3508 )
```

Here is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(2480,3508 ), false, 0);
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.width/25, -self.view.frame.height/25,2480,3508), afterScreenUpdates: true)
var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The screenshot is of the required size however it takes the screenshot of the entire view instead of just "overView".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)

Comment: It is possible to use XCUITest to take screenshots of elements as well

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For drawing of one view, just use this:

```
    // Begin context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    // Draw view in that context
    drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // And finally, get image
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

If you want to use it multiple times, probably extension would do the job:

//Swift4

```
extension UIView {

    func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {

        // Begin context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        // Draw view in that context
        drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        // And finally, get image
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if (image != nil)
        {
            return image!
        }
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

//Old Swift

```
extension UIView {

    func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage {

        // Begin context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        // Draw view in that context
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        // And finally, get image
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

To explain what those parameters do:

> UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() creates a temporary rendering
>   context into which the original is drawn. The first argument, size, is
>   the target size of the scaled image. The second argument, isOpaque is
>   used to determine whether an alpha channel is rendered. Setting this
>   to false for images without transparency (i.e. an alpha channel) may
>   result in an image with a pink hue. The third argument scale is the
>   display scale factor. When set to 0.0, the scale factor of the main
>   screen is used, which for Retina displays is 2.0 or higher (3.0 on the
>   iPhone 6 Plus).

More about it here http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

As for the draw call, Apple Docs explains it to detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html)

Comment: hey thanks for a quick reply. Can you explain to me the parameters inside
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and drawViewHierarchyInRect ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover explanation + added some more links

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with UIView in a UitableViewCell. the bottom is cut. Any suggestions??

Comment: you could use `return image ?? UIImage()` instead of the `if` block with force-unwrapping.

Answer (score 26):

swift 4 and iOS 10+

```
extension UIView {

  func screenshot() -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
      drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 15):

An alternative for [Alessandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582222/swift-take-sceenshot-of-a-uiview#46320343), a bit more brief and Swift style:

```
extension UIView {

    var snapshot: UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Taking Screen Short Use This Solution. Hear I can Done How to Take Screen Short `UIView` with `UIImage`.

```
let img = self.captureScreen() // CaptureScreen Is A Function
        let someNSDate = NSDate()
        let myTimeStamp = someNSDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

if let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.8)
{
    let filename = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Img_\(myTimeStamp).jpeg")
    SavedImage_Ary.insert("Img_\(myTimeStamp).jpeg", at: 0) // SavedImage Is A NSMutableArray Where You Can Store your Image
    //print(SavedImage_Ary)
    try? data.write(to: filename)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(SavedImage_Ary, forKey: "Saved_Image")
    Save_Img = true
    //            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    Select_Flag = "textdata"
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photovc") as! UINavigationController
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK : Function

func captureScreen() -> UIImage
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(Capture_View.frame.size, false, 0);
    Capture_View.drawHierarchy(in: Capture_View.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func screenShotMethod()->UIImage
    {
        let layer = self.view.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return screenshot!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.x and iOS 10+ with fallback solution:

```
extension UIView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
                drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
            drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? UIImage()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically need a `UIImage` but a `UIView` is fine, you can just use :

```
let snapshotView = yourView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview