# How to save image from imageView to Photo Library?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, photo-gallery

I need to save the photo of imageView to a gallery, when I click on the "Add" button on the navigation bar. I'm trying to save it, but I have a  "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error. Maybe someone knows, where is the problem?

```
class ViewControllerFilters2: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var filteredImage: UIImage?
var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if imageView.image == nil {
        imageView.image = filteredImage!
    }

     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "✔", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)))

}

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func image (_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: change `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` to `picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I change, but the same problem.

Comment: Just check the link. Already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858152/4747927

Comment: do you want to save the image from image gallery itself? where is the picker controller initialised and called from?

Comment: can you let us know error printed on console, can help to go to direction toward solution?

Comment: When I compile the app, it doesn't have an error. But when I click on Bar Button Item, which should to save my photo, the app is broken and I have an error "Thread 19: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: 2019-10-01 18:53:48.876331+0300 PhotoEditor[5994:1802712] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Answer (score 0):

The method getting called on tick/add button seems wrong, the target should be uibarbutton item for calling method:

```
     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "✔", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)))
```

Change selector for saving the image which will have code for saving the image to albums like:

```
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "✔", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveImage))
```

and the save image method may be like:

```
    @objc func saveImage() {
    if let pickedImage = imageView.image {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
   }
```

Also , in imagePickerController didFinish method assign the image to image view so that new image would be saved on click of add.

**EDIT**

As per crash log, add usage in formation in your plist for NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription as:

[image]

Hope it helps.. :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what you mean in the last sentence. I change all you said. But what I need to do with imagePickerController?

Comment: Okey, I add it. But when I click on the navigation button "Add", I have an alert  my photo save. But when I open the gallery, there aren't my photo

Comment: @kosya_kosia does your image has image at time of saving the image to gallery?