# Take screenshot of visible area of UIScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, screenshot

I have a UIScrollView as subview of a view controller main view.  I'm trying to save a screenshot of whatever is visible in the frame of the UIScrollView only.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageScrollView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: 0)

```
    view.layer.render(in: context!)
    let visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    let popupImageView = UIImageView(image: visibleScrollViewImage)
    popupImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    popupImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
    popupImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 400), size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 400))

    imageScrollView.removeFromSuperview()

    view.addSubview(popupImageView)
```

The part with the popupImageView is just to test out and see what is actually saving, it seems there is some offset problem, the horizontal axis is fine but i seem to be getting just the top third of the image I want, and above that is just dark space.

Seems like it must be a pretty easy solution but I've searched through all similar questions and can't find an answers.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Check this answer:
To get the screenshot, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956500/10842413

Comment: I don’t think you got the question, I need the screenshot from the uiscrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  If I do it with a `UITableView` control, it works.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func snapTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageScrollView.bounds.size, true, 1.0)
        imageScrollView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: imageScrollView.bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            myImageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, my hero you’ve saved me!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
func screenShotMethod()->UIImage
{
  let layer = self.imageScrollView.layer
  let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

  layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
  let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return screenshot!
}
```

Comment: When I do that now I get a completely blank image.

Comment: Are you calling this function on button click or on screen loading?

Comment: On button click, the uiscrollview has an image view that I zoom and move about inside the scroll view, then I click save button to save exactly what’s visible in the scroll view

Comment: Can you share some code to check the problem? Or first try to add the scrollview in a view and take the screenshot of that view