# Taking a snapshot of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I am making a tvOS app and I want it to look similarly to the Movies app. Therefore I have a `UICollectionView`. Now my cells are not just simple `UIImageView`s, but are rather somewhat more complicated.

I still want to have the nice focus visual effect (making the cell image bigger and having the light effect on it when the user swipes the remote). So what I am trying to do is render my cell, then take a snapshot of it and then show this snapshot instead of the cell itself. This is how I do it:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot : UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ContentCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! ContentCell
    cell.update()
    let cellSnapshot = cell.snapshot

    let snapshotCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SnapshotCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SnapshotCell
    snapshotCell.snapshotImageView.image = cellSnapshot
    return snapshotCell
}
```

However, all this does is show a black cell. Any ideas what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: UIView has a `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` method, is there a reason you're not using that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)

In Swift it will be smth like that:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot : UIImage? {
        var image: UIImage? = nil
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            self.layer.renderInContext(context)
            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```