# SKView drawRect not getting called

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to get screen capture working on my iOS SpriteKit game using this [code](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) (by Aroth)

Basically I need to replace the SKView of my UIViewController with my own  ScreenCaptureView (see the link). I changed the ScreenCaptureView in the example to derive from SKView instead of UIView.

I override loadView function in my game UIViewController class:

```
- (void)loadView
    {
        ScreenCaptureView *newView = [[ScreenCaptureView alloc] init];
        newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320);//hard code for now
        newView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        self.view = newView;
        [newView setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"loadView %x", (int)newView);
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad view %x %f x %f", (int)self.view ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

But its not working. The drawRect in ScreenCaptureView never gets called.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: is the loadview called ?

Comment: yes, loadView is called

Comment: try doing the same in viewdidlaod instead of loadview

Comment: I already did. No deal.

Comment: do setneedsdisplay before the line self.view=newView

Comment: See answer with the most votes. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview/18925301#18925301)