# take screenshot of a part of a single view and not the whole view hierarchy

Tags: ios, screenshot

I would like to take partial screenshot of only 1 view in view hierarchy. The method I found for partial screenshoting is `drawViewHierarchyInRect(_:afterScreenUpdates:)`, however this captures the while view hierarchy which I don't want.

This image shows what I mean

[image]

I only want to take a partial screenshot of a single view- in my case I want to take the screenshot of green area of the red view. How can I achieve that?

edit: the green area of red view is going to be shown in more than 1 view controller. The red view is large image and I do not want to draw that image on every view controller transition. I am thinking that it would be less intensive for iOS to just pass a small image(area covered by green color) around instead of large one

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need a partial screenshot? (i.e. is it merely for debugging purposes?)

Comment: sure. I edited my question.

Comment: yes. green color only shows the area of the red view I want to screenshot.

Comment: and size is fixed or different ?

Comment: if your size is fixed then you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview . just set size according to your green area.

Comment: it is determined by the screenHeight. 15% of the screen height on smaller devices 10 on bigger and so on. I added a number to make things easier to explain

Comment: Yep, that's great. Thank you! Be sure to post as an answer.