# Is it possible to capture a UIImage screenshot of a UIReplicantView?

Tags: uiview, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics, calayer

There are [a lot of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview) to take a screengrab of a `UIView`. The de facto way to capture a `UIView` "screengrab" of a `UIView` is `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` which returns a `UIReplicantView` (subclass of `UIView`).

Is there a way to create a `UIImage` from this seemingly recalcitrant class?

Answer (score 0):

This is the extension we used to capture `UIView` into `UIImageView`. The solution doesn't contain any usage of `UIReplicatView` as you suggested. But it has been working great for us:

```
extension UIView {
    // Note: only return the image after viewDidAppear called
    func takeScreenShot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)

        if let scrollView = self as? UIScrollView {
            let offset = scrollView.contentOffset
            UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.translateBy(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y);
        }

        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```