# How to merge multiple images like Snapchat?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, snapchat

I wanted to add emoticons, images in single image like we do in Snapchat and save the image with all the images added.

I have done adding, rotating, pinch, zoom functionality, but how to save the image with all the images added with their position is the point where I'm stuck.

Comment: `how to save the image with all the images added` That could depend on how you create this image. Please show the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This allows you to kind of 'screenshot' of the screen or a part of it.  it takes the viewHierarchy shown on screen within the given frame and captures it as a new image. regardless of layers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to take a screenshot of the whole view and save it as one image ? for that you could use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925301/1480331

If not, then you have to create some kind of template that would save the locations, rotations, sizes and all the details so you could render them later.