# Generate UIViewController Thumbnail - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to generate a small thumbnail of a view controller in a UIView?

For instance, I would want a smaller version of `MyViewController` to show up where `UIImageView` is showing up in the following image. I am using screenshots right now, but I feel it would be better to just show a snapshot of the view controller like how long-pressing a UITableViewCell will present a snapshot of the view controller. Is it possible to do this?

[image: example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)

Comment: you can change frame of the view, or apply transformation. Also as you said generate snapshot(image) of the view, and display it in the modal VC  :)