# Mixing faces of two persons

Tags: iphone

I have two images that I want to split each into 3 parts. If I click on the first image, the first part for eg forehead then second image first part i.e forehead will come by replacing first part and remaining two parts of the first image should be unaltered. Likewise all three parts should change while clicking that part how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a set of `UIButton` objects stacked on top of eachother with user interaction enabled and set the images in those.. then when one button is tapped, you check which one was tapped based on `sender` or `tag` and hide the button pressed, but show the next one underneath it?  When you get to the last button in the stack, show the top button again.

This would pretty much be a `switch-case` just setting hidden to yes/no.

Comment: That was a nice idea and i have another issue can i scroll each part for eg if i have 3 images if i scroll first part of first image to left(right) third(first) image will come by replacing the first part do you have any idea abot this???

Comment: For something like that... you'd be better off doing something like a paging style `UIScrollView` .. you'd need one for each body section.  It would let you swipe left/right with new images.

Comment: ok i need another thing that how
 can i save the mixed image??

Comment: Look into this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically  ..please consider marking this question as answered (little checkmark next to my post) and asking a new question for future questions.  Best of luck!