# How can I take screenshot from code on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot

How can I take screenshot from code?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to take a screenshot programmatically on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically-on-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2353-possible-make-screenshot-programmatically-2.html

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(Background.bounds.size);
[Background.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```