# How can I make a screenshot programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

How can I make a screenshot programmatically in iOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take screenshot from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945800/take-screenshot-from-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I take screenshot from code on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945800/how-can-i-take-screenshot-from-code-on-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have fun

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *myScreenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```