# What is the name of the method for screenshot on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I was wondering if there was a specific method called when we press the 2 buttons of the iPhone (using Home-Button & Power on/off) to take a screenshot. If yes, I would known his name to use her in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a `UIGetScreenImage()` function that you could use to capture the screen. Apple no longer allows use of that function in App Store apps, so you have a few other options. `CALayer` has a `-renderInContext:` method—[Google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=calayer+renderincontext)—that you can use to copy a view’s contents to a graphics context; this does not, however, work for OpenGL content, video, or live imagery from a device’s camera. I’m not sure about solutions for the first two, but for the latter—getting images from the camera—you’ll need to use the AVFoundation framework.

Comment: I need it for the camera =/ I look AVFoundation

Comment: AVFoundation is not what I need =/

Comment: Yeah, it is. If you want to capture still images or video from the camera, you use AVFoundation.

Comment: I want to take a screenshot when the camera is running, I think AVFoundation is like the method takePicture().

Answer (score 0):

It is a system level service for which the app never receives any notification or method call.

Comment: Too bad for me, it was to answered at this question : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947135/take-a-screenshot-from-the-camera-view)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that would be a native method, not accessible from the IPhone SDK. In what context are you going to be using this? You might be looking for this - [Take screenshot from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945800/take-screenshot-from-code)