# What is the way to take a screenshot in app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot

On iPhone, is there a way to tap a rounded rect button and take a screenshot, I don't want my users taking a photo by pressing sleep+home button! What are the code and frameworks needed?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Class method that will return a UIImage of the UIView and CGRect you pass to it:

```
+ (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view withArea:(CGRect)screenRect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Can I add newImage to UIImage *pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"];
in other function? And in what format is newImage?