# Hide UIButton before taking a screenshot

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I need to take a screenshot of the app. There is a button to trigger it, but I don't want the button to appear in the screenshot.

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction) takePicture:(id) sender {
    button.hidden = YES;

    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);

    // Save the captured image to photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    button.hidden = NO;
}
```

But the button still appears in the screenshot. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you capture the screen before the runloop could refresh the view (ie before it could hide the button)

you should try to change your code into something like this:

```
- (IBAction) takePicture:(id) sender {
    button.hidden = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(takeScreenShot) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];                    
}

- (void)takeScreenShot {
    CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
    CGImageRelease(screen);

    // Save the captured image to photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    button.hidden = NO;

}
```

this should take the screenshot after the runloop has removed your button.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timer to fire after the button is hidden, i.e.:

```
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(captureScreenshot) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and then move the screen capturing code to your ***captureScreenshot*** method.

One more thing: UIGetScreenImage() is an undocumented method call, use of which will probably result in your application being rejected. You should instead use CALayer's **[renderInContext:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext:)** method --see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically) for an example.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I'm aware about UIGetScreenImage. Just need to quickly prototype something. Not going to be a published app.