# MPMoviePlayerController: How to turn off sound during requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app I record a movie, save it to the PhotosAlbum, and request then creation of a thumbnail using the code

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL_];
NSArray *times = @[@(1.1)];
[self.player requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:times timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

This works fine, but during the thumbnail creation, `MPMoviePlayerController` plays the sound of the movie, although the movie is not visible, which is annoying.
**How can I turn the sound off** just of this particular `MPMoviePlayerController`? The `MPMoviePlayerController` class has apparently no property to control this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line after creating your player:

```
self.player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

Comment: This was the missing piece! Although the solution that I found by myself works perfectly, your answer solves the problem more directly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer in [How to mute/unmute audio when playing video using MPMoviePlayerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948661/how-to-mute-unmute-audio-when-playing-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller%3E) it is not possible to turn off the sound of a `MPMoviePlayerController`.
However I found in [Creating Thumbnail for Video in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963577/creating-thumbnail-for-video-in-ios) a much easier way to create thumbnails, which does not play sound and is synchronous so that handling of asynchronous callbacks is not required.
For convenience, I copy it here:

1. Add the `AVFoundation` framework to you app.
2. `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`
3. Add the following code:

   `UIImage *theImage = nil;
   AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:contentURL options:nil];
   AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
   generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
   NSError *err = NULL;
   CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
   CGImageRef imgRef = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
   theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
   CGImageRelease(imgRef);`