# screenshot of my app that contains both UIKit and Camera

Tags: iphone

I want to take Screen Shot of my Application containing both UIKit and Camera Elements, Actually my application is interior Decoration Application in Iphone. So requirement is when we done with decorating furniture on camera we take screenshot, that contains both UIKit and Camera element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Delegate Function of UIImagePicker
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw the image returned by the camera sample buffer into the context.
    // Draw it into the same sized rectangle as the view that is displayed on the screen.

    float menubarUIOffset = 44.0;
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height-menubarUIOffset)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    // Render the camera overlay view into the graphic context that we created above.
    [cameraOverlayVCObject cameraOverlayVCObject.view inContext:context];

    // Retrieve the screenshot image containing both the camera content and the overlay view
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // here is that final Image I am storing into Saved Photo Albums/ Library
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // I dont want my Camera to be Closed
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    self.view.hidden = NO;
}

// now got Picture from Camera need to Render Context on it here is Function
- (void)renderView:(UIView*)view inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // -renderInContext: renders in the coordinate space of the layer,
    // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    // Center the context around the window's anchor point
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, [view center].x, [view center].y);
    // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, [view transform]);
    // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
                          -[view bounds].size.width * [[view layer] anchorPoint].x,
                          -[view bounds].size.height * [[view layer] anchorPoint].y);

    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
    [[view layer] renderInContext:context];

    // Restore the context
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    [appDelegate.cameraPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

anything couldn't understandable, feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

use this,

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

This will allow you to capture a screenshot of your app and it will be saved in photos in your iPhone.

Comment: I am gone through with all these solutions, This is will only Capture Above view as Image not Camera Element. I want them captured both at the same time. UIImages or Button I added on CameraView + CameraView (mean what I am watching with Camera).. I think it would be done with AV Foundation but don't know how, if anyone knows please help. I am gone through this tutorial http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1714/_index.html but its Delegate Function doesn't get called. any suggestion?