# How to take printout from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, printing, uiscrollview

I have a print button in my app. If I click the button it should print the screen.
My problem is if the screen has a scrollview and it has contents more than screen size. It should print the whole content of the screen. the printout may take 2 or 3 pages. Is there any sample code or project for print the screen not by taking photos or screen shots.

Comment: Basically you convert the scroll view to an image file and then print that.  I've done the same thing, only sending the image as an email attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your whole data into HTML format and use a WebView to display data. For taking printout from iPhone app, you need to create a Pdf file from your webview content then take print out of this pdf file. Here I am giving you sample code, its properly working in my app.

1) include QuartzCore framework and import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" in ViewController.h file.

2) In ViewController.h file use following code

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate, UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate>
 {
       UIWebView *theWebView;
       int imageName;
       double webViewHeight;
 }

 -(void) takeSnapshot;
 - (void) drawPdf;
 -(void) printContent:(NSData *) data;
```

3) On viewDidLoad method use following code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString *htmlString=@"<html><body><img src=\"blue.png\" alt=\"Blue Image\" />  <h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p><h1>Hi, himanshu mahajan</h1><p> I am from Vinove Software service</p></body></html>";

     UIBarButtonItem *generate=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Print" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(printBtnPressed)];
     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:generate];

      theWebView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
      [theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
      theWebView.scrollView.bounces=NO;
      [self.view addSubview:theWebView];

      imageName=0;
      webViewHeight=0.0;
 }
```

4) method definitions

```
-(void) printBtnPressed
{
   [self takeSnapshot];

    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo.pdf"];

    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    [self printContent:data];
}

-(void) takeSnapshot
{

   webViewHeight=[[theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];

   CGRect screenRect=theWebView.frame;
   double currentWebViewHeight = webViewHeight;

   while (currentWebViewHeight > 0)
   {
     imageName ++;

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     [[UIColor blackColor] set];
     CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

     [theWebView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

     UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageName]];

     if(currentWebViewHeight < 416)
     {
         CGRect lastImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 416 - currentWebViewHeight, theWebView.frame.size.width, currentWebViewHeight);
          CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], lastImageRect);    

          newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
          CGImageRelease(imageRef);
      }
      [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

      [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,416);"];
      currentWebViewHeight -= 416;
    }

   [self drawPdf];
  }


  - (void) drawPdf
  {
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, webViewHeight);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

    double currentHeight = 0.0;
   for (int index = 1; index  <= imageName ; index++)
   {
      NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
      UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

      [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];
      currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;
     }
     UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
  }

   -(void) printContent:(NSData *) data
   {
      UIPrintInteractionController *print = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

       print.delegate = self;
       UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
       printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
      //printInfo.jobName = @"Information";
       printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
       print.printInfo = printInfo;
       print.showsPageRange = YES;
       print.printingItem = data;
       UIViewPrintFormatter *viewFormatter = [self.view viewPrintFormatter];
       viewFormatter.startPage = 0;
       print.printFormatter = viewFormatter;

       UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {};

       [print presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all data into HTML and print it,

```
- (void) didPressPrintExpenseButton {
   UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];    
   printController.delegate = self;

   void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
        ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) NSLog(@"Print error: %@", error);
        };

   UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];    
   printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral; 
   printInfo.jobName = @"Expense";  
   printController.printInfo = printInfo;

   UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *htmlFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                                     initWithMarkupText:[self getHtmlInvoiceDescription]];  
   htmlFormatter.startPage = 0;
   htmlFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins    
   htmlFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;    
   printController.printFormatter = htmlFormatter;  
   [htmlFormatter release]; 
   printController.showsPageRange = YES;
   [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];   
}

- (NSString *) getHtmlInvoiceDescription {
    NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [htmlString appendString:@"<html> \n"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"<body> \n"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"<table border='0' cellpadding='5' width='100%' >\n"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"<tr>\n"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td style=\"width='50%%'\"> %@ </td>", [self.addressString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br>"]];
    //TODO change the image url here
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iTunesArtwork.png"];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString * dataString = [data base64EncodedString]; // Your own base 64 converter
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td style=\"width='50%%'\" align=\"right\"> <img src=\"data:image/png;base64,%@\" width='%.0f' height='%.0f' > </td>", dataString,
     verifyHeader.frame.size.height * image.size.width/image.size.height, verifyHeader.frame.size.height];
    [htmlString appendString:@"\n</tr> \n </table>"];

    [htmlString appendFormat:@"\n<h2> %@ </h2>", NSLocalizedString(@"Expense", @"")];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n<table border='1' cellpadding='5' width='100%'>"];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n<tr>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td style=\"width='50%%' \"> %@ </td>", NSLocalizedString(@"Date: ", @"")];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td width='50%%'> %@ </td>", [self getFormattedDateString:self.expense.date]];
    [htmlString appendString:@"</tr>"];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n<tr>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", NSLocalizedString(@"Reference no: ", @"")];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", self.expense.referenceNo];
    [htmlString appendString:@"</tr>"];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n<tr>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", NSLocalizedString(@"Customer name: ", @"")];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", self.expense.customerName];
    [htmlString appendString:@"</tr>"];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n<tr>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", NSLocalizedString(@"Product description: ", @"")];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<td> %@ </td>", self.expense.productDescription];
    [htmlString appendString:@"</tr>"];

    [htmlString appendString:@"\n</table>"];
    [htmlString appendString:@"\n</body> \n</html>"];

    NSString * tempString = [NSString stringWithString:htmlString];
    [htmlString release];   
    return tempString;
}
```

Also, there is a way to convert your info in PDF and then you can print that. 
Find apple documentation [iPhone print API guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW1).

Comment: thanks but can you give sample code or project for convert the info into pdf and then print that as you mentioned above

Comment: @NAZIK, I have same situation. I want to take the print out of my content that is on scrollview. Please can you give me sample code??

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to [take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically), and print that. In that case you would just print the screenshot.

Comment: sorry I mentioned above its not about taking screen shots it is all about direct printing

Comment: That's what I said. Print the screenshot.