# save the captured image with the overlay image to the photoalbum in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

How can i merge the captured photo from UIImagePickerController and cameraoverlay view?
Then i want to save it to the photos album.

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i didn't get your question earlier.. One way to do is that to capture the screenshot programmatically and then edit the image according to your requirements and save it.

This should help...
[How to take a screenshot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It will save only the captured image.But i want to save captured image with the overlay image.

Answer (score 3):

I would create an image context, then write both images into it. Then use    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to save to album. Here is an example where I put a logo on the saved image when called from a button. In your case the brand image will be your overlay and the imageToSave will be the image from the UIImagePickerController. Modify to suit. Hopefully it will help:

```
 - (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender{

    //add brand to image
    UIImage *BrandImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brand.png"];
    UIImage* imageToSave = [imageView image]; //get current imageView
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.image.size.width, self.imageView.image.size.height);

    //get screen size for retina or non retina
    UIScreen *MainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    UIScreenMode *ScreenMode = [MainScreen currentMode];
    CGSize Size = [ScreenMode size];

//position brand logo according to screen size
    if (Size.width == 640) {
        topImageRect = CGRectMake(self.imageView.image.size.width - 160, self.imageView.image.size.height - 80, 141, 53);
    }
    else
    {
        topImageRect = CGRectMake(self.imageView.image.size.width - 80, self.imageView.image.size.height - 40, 71, 27);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

    [imageToSave drawInRect:imageRect];
    [BrandImage drawInRect:topImageRect];

    UIGraphicsPopContext();                             

    // get a UIImage from the image context
    UIImage* SavedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // clean up drawing environment
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Save it to the camera roll / saved photo album
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(SavedImage, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help to work with camera overlay view and saving overlay clicked image in to library http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/ios4-take-photos-with-live-video-preview-using-avfoundation/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i am using UIImagePickerController for capturing the photo.do have any idea on this instead of AVFoundation?

Comment: then you can try for this one too .http://idevhub.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/