# Recreate Instagram UITabBar center tab behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Using the traditional `UITabBar + UINavigationController` design paradigm how do you achieve the effect of Instagram's central tab tap - the whole `UITabBarController` goes down revealing the capture `UIViewController` that is responsible for taking photos.

How do you replicate such a behavior? The most interesting part for me is, how exactly do you put a modal view below the actual `UITabBarController`? Right now the closest I could get to is presenting a `UIViewController` with a traditional `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical` presentation style which is totally not what I want:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (!recordDisplayed){
        SGRecordViewController *customController = [[SGRecordViewController alloc] init];
        customController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        customController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        [self presentViewController:customController animated:YES completion:nil];
        recordDisplayed = YES;
        previousIndex = [self tabBarController].selectedIndex;
    }else{

        [self tabBarController].selectedIndex = previousIndex;

        recordDisplayed = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would enough to supplement this with changing the tab bar's frame in a `UIView animateWithDuration:` block?

Comment: @Mundi no, their effect is much more complex, they animate the whole view to go *down*, revealing the view that was **behind** the tab bar - this is the problem.

Comment: You can make a screenshot of the current view or screen - push a new view controller - and then animate the screenshot out. That is how it is done normally.

Comment: @Mundi Should I like put the screenshot of the view on the window of the app and the move it down? Sound like a good ideas to me!

Comment: Yes, more or less like this. I did this recently because I had to push a new view controller while remaining at the same view hierarchy. So I just reconfigured the view and animated out the screenshot of the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to take a screenshot of the view and animate it out with your custom transition.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285889/take-screenshot-programmatically-ios-5) answers how to generate the screenshots based on view or window.