# How to take a screenshot using code on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimage, screenshot

How to take a screenshot programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot programmatically on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically-on-ios)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` for this purpose.

For example :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage*theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData*theImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0 ); //you can use PNG too
[theImageData writeToFile:@"example.jpeg" atomically:YES];
```

Here

**1.** First i take the image context, i've given it as `myView` which is a webview, you can give whatever you wish for. This takes the image of webview that can be seen on the screen.

**2** Using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` i convert the screenshot of my webview into an image.

**3.** By using `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` i ask it end the context.

**4.** I'm saving the image into an `NSData` because i had to mail the screenshot. And keep it in `NSData` seemed a good option if it is used to send or save.

**EDIT:** To add it to the camera roll you need to write:

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage,nil,NULL,NULL);` after `UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: I have implemented this into my code but it doesn't seem to be saving the screenshot in the camera roll. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @RafeeSkull-manJenkins, to save it to CameraRoll you need to use `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, check my edit.

Comment: I think this code doesn't work with Camera or OpenGL frames, or maybe I'm missing something...?

Comment: @iNoob tried this but found it didn't contain status bar and navigation bar, only the view below navigation bar. How to do a full screen snap?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/641062).It also takes care of retina display.

Actually to explain the process,

- Choose a image context size (probably the layer size for which you need screen shot)
- Render the layer which you want to take screenshot in the created context
- Obtain the image from the context and you are done!

Comment: I just wanted to add a bit of explanation on my own. So chose to answer it.