# Screenshots in iOS

Tags: ios

Essentially I want to code a button which when pressed takes a screenshot of what is being displayed on the screen and saves it to the camera roll. I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140907/take-a-screenshot-using-code) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically/2203293#2203293).

I get an error on this line

```
[self.myImageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Saying

```
Receiver type 'CALAyer' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into that error the other day.

You've forgotten to add the QuartzCore framework to your project!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please vote to close out duplicate questions, not answer them with duplicate answers.

Comment: @iWasRobbed 1731 < 3000

Comment: Oh, missed the comment! Voting done! Will remove my answer!

Comment: @Undo Even if a person can't vote to close, there is no need to add an answer to an obvious duplicate.

Comment: @rmaddy http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4286/215468

Comment: @Undo The answer you linked talks about questions on SO that should have been asked on "meta". That's not the case here.

Comment: @rmaddy Last sentence - *'I use the same approach for duplicates, as well'* I'm not saying you're wrong, though. Ansa-closing isn't something I do. However, I figure it's a good idea to just give the OP what he wants - we *are* trying to keep people here.