# Dynamic UIView to UIImage is blank

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to create a UIView where I add 2 UIImageView inside and create an UIImage from this. Here is the method I use, but I get a blank UIImage.

Here is the code I use :

```
-(UIImage*)getFinalImage{

    CGRect rect = CadreImage.frame;

    UIView *dynaView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    UIImageView *frontCadre = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:TheImage];

    [dynaView addSubview:frontCadre];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(dynaView.bounds.size, dynaView.opaque, 0.0);
    [dynaView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: NSLog `rect`, `frontCadre`, etc. My guess is a messed up frame along the way.

Comment: frame seems okay :
`2012-07-17 18:49:20.203 Pixamaz[1095:907] w:320.000000
2012-07-17 18:49:20.215 Pixamaz[1095:907] h:367.000000`
Where H and W represent height and width.

Comment: oh did you ever add the dynaview to the screen? I believe you have to add that as a subview of your current view so the graphics can actually pull the pixel data in

Comment: I tried that too `[self.view addSubview:dynaView];`

Comment: Can you view the image if you just add the subview to the view instead of trying to take a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to grab a layer/screenshot (note this is for the whole screen and not a specific layer + handles retina displays):

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
else
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Can you also set a breakpoint and jump through the program to verify that TheImage is not nil?

Comment: TheImage is not nil. The code you use uses the same fonction as mine, it's awkward mine don't works.

Comment: It does use the same result... are you using a retina screen for this test though? or just simulator?

Comment: also can you try using 1.0 instead of 0.0 on the scale factor

Comment: I'm using my iPhone 4S (retina screen so), same result with 1.0.

Comment: the scale factor is meant to help the retina screen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically ... hmm

Comment: I have the same result with the simulator.