# I want to take screenshot of iPad which has UIKIT and OpenGL both in same view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to take screenshot of iPad which has UIKIT and OpenGL both in same view .i  tried to take screen shot using `[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`  Iam getting the screenshot but the area where OpenGl  is present comes in yellow color please help

Comment: This thread might help you.They consider two approaches

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically