# How can i write text on image and send it on mail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating an app that send photo on email,i have created gallery,now i want my app can write text on that photo and send it on email. Any suggestions? tutorials are acceptable.

Comment: use contexts and draw rect methods to draw text on image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest  but tricky, Add a `UIView` inside a `UIImageView` and  a `UILabel`, update with `yourimage` and `text`. Now take an `UIImage` by capture screenshot [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/1603234) and attach it with your email.

Comment: Do i have to put capture screen method in appdelegate because otherwise it dispaly error in this two line at "window"

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
    [self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

Comment: and if i will put this method in appdelegate than it will not capture image.

Comment: @chetan, dude!! You can place this code anywhere! Instead of `self.window` you should pass the `UIView` that I've given in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create UIImageView with image then place UILabel with clear background on image view, and finally make a UIImage using Core Graphics.
Something like this:

```
UIImage *bcg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bcg];
imgView.frame = CGRectZero;//Some frame
[self addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];

UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, imgView.frame.size.height - 20, imgView.frame.size.width, 20)];
text.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
text.text = @"Some text";
[imgView addSubview:text];

UIImage *resultImage = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width,
                                       self.bounds.size.height)); 

[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width,
                              self.bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);

[viewImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                 0,
                                 imageSize.width,
                                 imageSize.height)
            blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];

resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

This method easier to debug than draw image and text in context.