# Camera controller not working when taking screenshot

Tags: ios, uiimage, calayer, screen-capture, camera-overlay

I took screenshot of overlay image with background camera controller. But background cameracontroller layer is hiding when taking picture

code:

```
CGRect rect = [previewView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[previewView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera preview layer is not a common CALayer and is not taken into account with render in context. Render in context works only with a kind of CALayer. The most effettive way is get a screenshot directly from the camera buffer.

Comment: Is there any way to take UIImage with cameralayer. I searched so many tutorials. help me..

Comment: Unfortunatly no as I know in an easy way. One time ago it was accepted to use a special function UIGetScreenImage() but is a private API, if you are building for AppStore most likely you will get a reject. I suggest you to read this SO answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically and this tech note from Apple you will find it very helpful http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1714/_index.html