# Sharing a mkmapview screenshot

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, share, apple-maps

I have a map with lots of stuff on it, which I'd like to share in form of a picture/screenshot.

However, as far as i know, the map --both iOS 6 for Apple and iOS 5 for Google-- is copyrighted and I can't simply do that. 
I thought of Google Static Maps API, but I didn't find something similar for the Apple maps to be available.
How could I share a mapview picture without violating their rules and still using the MapKit framework ?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200736/how-to-take-a-screenshot-programmatically

Comment: @Kalpesh I can take the screenshot without any problem, my question is how can i share it legally.

Answer (score 2):

I'm struggling myself with laws of sharing Apple map snapshot with track information on it. Sent an enquiry to Apple technical support, got redirected to App Review team, got only an answer with guidelines links so far. Read the license info from tapping on "Legal" link and yes all rights are "reserved". Sent a request to Tom Tom asking if they would feel bad about such personal sharing.

Situation is rather sad for Apple if we can't as I'd have to resort to OSM map soon for showing tracks and Apple map use cases in my app (and I guess many others) come to zero.

For the answer, I'm thinking about leaving only one option for saving the map/track snapshot: "Save to camera roll". If user can take a screenshot at any moment, I can just prepare the "better" image with no toolbars etc, and then users can do with image in the camera roll whatever they need to do? I only provide the image they could have cropped themselves? I don't need to care if and how do they share?

So it is just a suggestion to run through and see if it sounds reasonable...

Comment: Well, I'm still struggling whit this issue. I could save the image, indeed, in the camera roll. But, users are lazy and it would be just another frustrating step before share, if I create this copyright "bypass" to reopen their map screenshot. Currently, I'm generating some similar layout with Google Static Maps. It's similar, but not exactly the same as the normal MKMapView would be. It's sad...

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would you like to share it?
If by email, then you can send the map embedded in the email body, so it is even interactive.

Comment: Yes, in e-mail there are many possibilities, including html embed, but I'd like some "universal" method which i could use for twitter or facebook in form of a picture.

Comment: Then you have to use some open source maps or maps with licenses that allow you to make pictures of it and distribute it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, view.size.height);
    // passing negative values to flip the image
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    [[appDelegate.scatterPlotView layer] renderInContext:currentContext];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenshot;
}
```

Just add your mapview To uiview and the pas uiview to this method and now you can share your mapview image to anywhere.